# How to access snakemake.input[0]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake

This should be a simple problem, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. I have a very, very simple Snakefile (shown below):

```
rule test:
    input:
        "/home/username/input_data"
    script:
        "scripts/test.py"
```

And in my `test.py` file, I am doing the following:

```
import snakemake
print(snakemake.input[0])
```

But I cannot access `snakemake.input[0]`. The [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts) have an example as simple as mine, but I can't get it to work. Additionally, in a Python interactive shell I am able to `import snakemake`, but I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named snakemake
```

when importing it from my `test.py` script.

I am calling `snakemake test` from the command line in the same folder as the `Snakefile` to run this.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Can you try not importing snakemake?

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande, I've just edited my post. I was able to fix my problems by uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Please don't post the solution/answer as an edit. If you solved your own problem, you can post it as an answer (and even accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by removing a snakemake installation at `/usr/bin/snakemake`, then reinstalling by following the installation guide [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html)